# csvde to find 1 user based on SamAccountName

Tags: active-directory

I want to use csvde to find 1 user based on SamAccountName and export all the details about that person to a CSV file.

The problem I am having is filtering by SamAccountName

```
csvde -f search.txt -p subtree -l SamAccountName,CN,Distinguedname -r (&(objectClass=User)(SamAccountName=jon.doe))
```

I get an error saying that it didn't know what SamAccountName is

I need it to run from command line ( no powershell or vbscript please )

Comment: Why no PowerShell?

Comment: im going to run the command from kix

Comment: Is it an administrative script or a logon script?

Comment: will be running as a logon script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple filters, you have set filter in quotations marks

```
csvde -f search.txt -p subtree -l "sAMAccountName,cn,distinguedName" -r "(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=jon.doe))"
```